Work out the correct path for Python mock.patch
I am aware the basics of the path for mock.path, but it's increasingly difficult to work out the correct path when the object is encapsulated by layers of dynamic construction, eg. django viewflow how to mock viewflow handlers
eg.
forms.py
def get_options():
    # this is the one I want to mock
    ...


class Form(...):
    field = Field(choices=get_options)
    ...

I am just making up stuff here to show some complications here
flow.py
from forms import Form

class Flow(...):
    start = (
        flow.Start(..., form_class=Form).Next(...)
    )

I have tried mock.patch('forms.get_options') and it didn't work. I suspect the get_options reference has been changed somehow.
I am wondering if there are some print stack statement to help to show me the path I need to patch eg.
forms.py
def get_options():
    # print the stack here and output something like
    # "complicated_dynamic_class_creation.flow.instance.blah.blah.get_options"

    # this is the one I want to mock
    ...

What I have also tried to get the dot notation of the current context that the function is being executed in
import inspect

def get_current_function_dot_notation():
    # Get the current stack frame
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    # Get the caller frame
    caller_frame = frame.f_back
    
    # Get the function name
    function_name = caller_frame.f_code.co_name
    
    # Get the module name
    module_name = caller_frame.f_globals["__name__"]
    
    # Try to get the class name (if the function is a method of a class)
    class_name = None
    if 'self' in caller_frame.f_locals:
        class_name = caller_frame.f_locals['self'].__class__.__name__
    elif 'cls' in caller_frame.f_locals:
        class_name = caller_frame.f_locals['cls'].__name__
    
    # Construct the dot notation
    if class_name:
        dot_notation = f"{module_name}.{class_name}.{function_name}"
    else:
        dot_notation = f"{module_name}.{function_name}"
    
    return dot_notation

# Example usage
def get_options():
    print(get_current_function_dot_notation())
    ...

This returns the 'forms.get_options` and it doesn't work in my "flow" case.

A module-level class definition is executed when the module is imported, and the field attribute of Form is initialized as a Field object (I think you actually mean ChoiceField here) with choices being a  reference to forms.get_options at the time of execution. Patching forms.get_options afterwards doesn't change the reference already stored as choices in field (and in the actual source code choices is really a property).
A more viable approach is to use patch.object to patch the choices attribute of Form.field instead, which is also in general a way to avoid having to figure out the import path of an object (which can be unavailable if the class comes from a factory):
from forms import Form

with patch.object(Form.field, 'choices', Mock(return_value=['A', 'B', ...])):
    ...


Thanks, it does make sense and gave me a better direction, unfortunately I am not able to mock the choices field easily as the attribute cannot be replaced somehow, I had to resort to mocking the whole form but the form reference is buried deep inside a few layers of logic, the most inner one I could find was def as_view(cls, **initkwargs): and the method is cached with a property.

I have changed my approach a bit to just mock the get_form_class of the view and I managed to fake the form.
